# ¿Cómo hago para comparar dos vectores dentro de un ArrayList?

Tags: java, array, netbeans, bucle-for, bucles

Buenos días tengo un problema y es que necesito ingresar un dato (String) y con ese dato hallar todos los vectores dentro del ArrayList que cumplan con el dato(String).

### Ejemplo:

En el array esta el (nombre, (Vector: edad))

Ingreso edad 18, entonces quiero que me imprima todos los arrays donde en el vector estén las edad 18.

---

Este es mi código:

```
public class Cocina {
public int n;
private Scanner sc;
private Receta receta;   
ArrayList<Receta> recetario = new ArrayList<>();

public Cocina() {
    sc = new Scanner(System.in);
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
    Cocina menu = new Cocina();
    menu.desplegarMenu();
}

private void consultarRecetaParticular() {
    System.out.println("Ingrese el ingrediente ");                  //Revisar esto
    String ingredienteBusca = sc.nextLine();
    for (int i = 0; i < recetario.size(); i++) {
        if (recetario.get(i).getIngredientes().equals(ingredienteBusca)) {
            System.out.println(recetario.get(i));
        }
    }


class Receta {
private String ingredientes[];
public String[] getIngredientes() {
    return ingredientes;
}
public void setIngredientes(String[] ingredientes) {
    this.ingredientes = ingredientes;
}
```

este seria el problema sin preguntar

```
    private void consultarRecetaParticular() {
    for (int i = 0; i < recetario.size(); i++) {
    if ((recetario.get(i).getIngredientes()).equals(recetario.get(i).getIngredientes()))  {
            System.out.println(recetario.get(i));
        }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Agrego código con explicación en comentarios.

```
private void consultarRecetaParticular() {
        System.out.println("Ingrese el ingrediente ");                  //Revisar esto
        String ingredienteBusca = sc.nextLine();

        for (int i = 0; i < recetario.size(); i++) {
            
            boolean contieneIngrediente = false;
            // recorrer cada ingrediente de la lista
            for (String ingrediente : recetario.get(i).getIngredientes()) {
                // se usa equals() para comparar cadenas
                if (ingrediente.equals(ingredienteBusca)) {
                    // si existe en esta lista terminar la iteración
                    contieneIngrediente = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            // hacer alguna acción con el elemento i del arreglo recetario
            if (contieneIngrediente) {
                // 
            }

        }

    }
```

Comment: gracias bro, pero tengo otra pregunta si quiero consultar las arrays que tengan tengan un ingrediente(arreglo) particular ejm En el array esta el (nombre, (Vector: edad que contiene 18)), otra array donde esta el (nombre, (Vector: edad que contiene 18), otra array donde esta el (nombre, (Vector: edad que contiene 17), quiero que me imprima 18. yo quiero imprimir los mismo pero sin preguntar seria como buscar las edades comunes, como hago?, ¿si me hice entender?

Comment: lo que pienso lo puse en la pregunta en la ultima parte ayuda plss

Comment: Con qué criterio tomaría la edad 18 e ignoraría la edad 17 si no se está preguntando nada?

Comment: buena pregunta mejor olvidalo xd gracias por la ayuda